# How to use kbmMWConfiguration.Configuration as Memory only

Tags: delphi

I know, that I can use the Configuration object to create files:

```
// Config.PrepareYAMLStorage;
// Config.PrepareBSONStorage;
// Config.PrepareJSONStorage;
   Config.PrepareXMLStorage;
```

These files are created automatically when the object is destroyed. I want to use the class as memory only, so I can persist the content of Config.Storage on a database.

Is there a variant of Storage, that has something like a Storage.AsString or how can I create a replacement of the exiting Storage, that can do this?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways.

The "intended" way is to create your own storage method for the configuration object.

If you want to have the data as JSON, you can inherit from kbmMW 's TkbmMWJSONConfigurationStorage and add a couple of methods that provides a string with the JSON data in it.

Eg.

```
TMyStorage = class(TkbmMWJSONConfigurationStorage)
protected
   function GetConfigurationAsString:string;
   procedure SetConfigurationAsString(const AString:string);
public
   property ConfigurationAsString:string read GetConfigurationAsString write SetConfigurationAsString;
end;
...
function TMyStorage.GetConfigurationAsString:string;
var
  str:TkbmMWJSONStreamer;
begin
  str:=TkbmMWJSONStreamer.Create;
  try
     Result:=str.SaveToUTF16String(&ON);
  finally
     str.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TMyStorage.SetConfigurationAsString(const AString:string);
var
  str:TkbmMWJSONStreamer;
  co:TkbmMWONCustomObject;
begin
  str:=TkbmMWJSONStreamer.Create;
  try
     co:=str.LoadFromUTF16String(AString);
     if co.IsObject then
     begin
          &ON.Free;
          &ON:=TkbmMWONObject(co);
     end
     else
         co.Free;
  finally
     str.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Then
var
myStorageInstance:TMyStorage;
begin
myStorageInstance:= TMyStorage.Create('somepathtojsonstorage',false);
Configuration.Storage:=myStorageInstance;
end;

Notice that this will still save and load the configuration to and from a file. If you want to prevent that, override the Save and Load methods and make them do nothing.
But it does provide you with a way to access the JSON storage as a string.
It however also prevents you from switching the storage out at will, since a complete registry based storage usually will not easily be able to be set from a string or read to a string.

/Kim/C4D